# PG:: Deployed to heroku "Error: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type integer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am getting a weird error in my app when its been pushed to heroku. The app runs fine one my local machine. I dont know if it's because I am using Mysql locally?

Here is the error I am getting:

```
2012-07-24T17:14:52+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type integer
2012-07-24T17:14:52+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "articles_users" ON "users"."id" = "articles_users"."user_id" WHERE "articles_users"."article_id" = 64 AND (1)):
2012-07-24T17:14:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:            <span>
2012-07-24T17:14:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:           <a data-action="like" data-id="<%= a.id %>" >
2012-07-24T17:14:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:           <%if user_signed_in?%>
2012-07-24T17:14:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:                   <%if a.likes.where(user_id = current_user.id).size == 0%>
2012-07-24T17:14:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:                           <%=image_tag("star.png", :width => "37", :height => "36", "data-action" => "star")%></a><span data-action="likes" style="vertical-align:10px; padding:8px;">
2012-07-24T17:14:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:                   <%else%>
2012-07-24T17:14:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:                           <%= image_tag("star-yellow.png", :width => "37", :height => "36", "data-action" =>"star")%></a><span data-action="likes" style="vertical-align:10px; padding:8px;">
```

Here the code from my view:

```
<a data-action="like" data-id="<%= a.id %>" >
    <%if user_signed_in?%>  
        <%if a.likes.where(user_id = current_user.id).size == 0%>   
            <%= image_tag("star.png", :width => "37", :height => "36", "data-action" => "star")%></a><span data-action="likes" style="vertical-align:10px; padding:8px;">
        <%else%>
            <%= image_tag("star-yellow.png", :width => "37", :height => "36", "data-action" => "star")%></a><span data-action="likes" style="vertical-align:10px; padding:8px;">
        <%end%>
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
<%if a.likes.where(user_id = current_user.id).size == 0%>
```

to

```
<%if !a.likes.include?(current_user)%>
```

And it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the where method like this.

```
a.likes.where(:user_id => :current_user.id)
```

not

```
a.likes.where(user_id = current_user.id)
```

I think this will work.

Comment: Nope. That caused it to search the wrong table, it searched the users table instead of the join table articles_users



`Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` INNER JOIN `articles_users` ON `users`.`id` = `articles_users`.`user_id` WHERE `articles_users`.`article_id` = 13 AND `users`.`user_id` = 1`